# How do i use Lotus Domino forms webquery save from serverside javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I have an lotus domino form that will be filled by the user of my web app. You can see it on the image below.

> [image: Blockquote]

As you know, those fields that use the client-side code will be filled automatically when the form is loaded and when the agent in web query save triggered. How do i recreate this "mechanism" when i'm using SSJS code to create this form?

FYI, i'm creating an API using SSJS to create this form. So the data that i'll receive from the front-end are those that filled by user. It'll be too much work if i have to code the fields that supposed to be filled by client-side code. And the front-end that i'm using is Angular.

Pardon my english.

Answer (score 0):

On a XPages there is the possibility to trigger and Query Save action, see http://www.xpageswiki.com/apps/wiki-xpages/wiki-xpages.nsf/page.xsp?documentId=C483F4FA895B5790C12578090038E377&action=openDocument#Set+fields+in+backend+document+in+QuerySave+event